# How would you go about proving that any complex line is a curve on the Riemann sphere?

Tags: complex-analysis

It is physically intuitive why a line (for example the complex line) in the complex plane would map to a circle (or the circumference) of the Riemann sphere, but how would you go about showing this fact mathematically?

Thanks

Comment: Don't you mean a *real* line (in $\mathbb{C}$)? And including $\infty$? Do you have the stereographic projection in mind? It seems to be somehow confusing..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that under stereographic projection, a point $A$ on the plane is mapped to the point $P(A)$ on the sphere that is collinear with $P(\infty)$ and $A$. It follows that if $\ell$ is a line in the plane, every point $P(x)$ for $x\in\ell$ is collinear with $P(\infty)$ and $x$, and hence is in $P(\infty)+\ell$, the unique plane containing $\ell$ and $P(\infty)$. Therefore, $\ell$ is mapped to $S^2\cap(P(\infty)+\ell)$, and the intersection of a sphere with a plane is a circle.

Note that this circle is not usually a great circle, unless $0\in\ell$. Other circles not containing $P(\infty)$ are mapped to circles on the plane, although I don't have a nice geometrical proof of this (you can work it out algebraically using a Mobius transformation).

[image: diagram]

Comment: nice answer, not sure why so many people want the question closed though